# Speed up AI obstacle detection in python pygame

Tags: python, pygame

I am trying to train a NEAT algorithm to play a simple game called 'curvefever'.
I was able to create a pygame version of curvefever and now I want to train the AI to play it. 
Therefore, the AI has to learn to avoid obstacles: borders surrounding the game and tracks that each player leaves behind, like in Snake.

At the moment I am doing this in the following way:

- Each player has a set of 'sensors' reaching forward that detect if and how far away an obstacle is.
- Each 'sensor' is a straight line consisting of several pygame rectangles.
- For each sensor it will detect if a collision with one of the obstacle rectangles occurred and calculate the distance of the collision to the player.
- Which sensor detected the collision and the distance of the collision is the information that goes to the neural network.

The problem is that this is very slow! Running 'python -m cProfile -s cumtime ai.py' I figured that it is the detection of obstacles that is slowing the script down, taking up about 50% of the total runtime.

**Please see some code below how I create the lines of sight:**

posx = x-position of player

posy = y-position of player

dir  = direction the player is going

dangle = is the degree-spacing between lines of sight

angle  = total range (in degrees) of lines of sight

[image: sketch illustrating the sensors]

```
def create_lines_of_sight(posx, posy, dir, dangle, angle, length):
    dirs = [xdir for xdir in np.ceil(np.arange(dir-angle,dir+angle,dangle))]

    d_posx = np.cos(np.deg2rad(dir))
    d_posy = np.sin(np.deg2rad(dir))

    return list(map(functools.partial(f_lrects,posx,posy,length), dirs))


def create_rects(posx, posy, d_posx, d_posy, i):
    return f_rect(posx+i*d_posx,posy+i*d_posy,1,1,0,curvefever.WHITE)

f_create_rect = create_rects

def create_line_of_rects(posx, posy, length,dir):
    l = pygame.sprite.Group()
    ladd = l.add

    d_posx = np.cos(np.deg2rad(dir))
    d_posy = np.sin(np.deg2rad(dir))
    i = [i for i in range(2,length,8)]
    ladd(map(functools.partial(f_create_rect,posx,posy,d_posx,d_posy),i))
    return l

f_lrects = create_line_of_rects
```

All obstacles are rectangles defined as:

```
class Rect(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self,x,y,width,height,dir,color):
        super().__init__()
        self.image = pygame.Surface([width, height])
        self.image.fill(color)
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()

        self.rect.centerx = x
        self.rect.centery = y
```

and are saved in a sprite group.

**What I tried**

I tried adding a map command to get rid of the for loop, that did not speed it up much.

I tried adding the function names to remove the function lookup, I read this makes it faster, but it didn't.

I tried detecting an obstacle using 'Bresenham's Line Algorithm' and checking if an obstacle (x,y) position overlaps with the line of sight. Although this was a faster it did not work as it often missed obstacles. This happened because the line of sight did not exactly match the obstacle centre (rectx,recty) although it did overlap with the rectangle itself.

What do other people use to detect obstacles (maybe in pygame)? Any tips on how I can make this faster or more efficient are very welcome.

Thank you very much for your help!

Comment: So the obstacles are the trails, how are you storing them? Are they a bunch of points? Or is this more like snake where it is in a grid and you can only move up,down,left,right?

Comment: The obstacles are all rectangles and saved as a sprite.group:

class Rect(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self,x,y,width,height,dir,color):
        super().__init__()
        self.image = pygame.Surface([width, height])
        self.image.fill(color)
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()

        self.rect.centerx = x
        self.rect.centery = y

Comment: and you can move in any direction

Comment: What is `dangle`, `angle`? Are these angles related to the "sensors"? Are these angles constant?

Comment: Yes, dangle and angle are related to sensors. I added a picture that I hope adds some clarification and both are constants

Comment: @Rabbid76 It says above the picture, dir is the direction the player is going, its not going to be constant as the player can move any direction

Comment: Hey, I'm currently working on curvefever in pygame. Could you please share your code. I'm stuck with the collsion of the "snake" itself. Thanks

Comment: Hi AutMai, absolutely. Please find the code on https://github.com/christianstassen/curvefever.git I haven't progressed much since. Have fun :)

Comment: Maybe you could try to check only a few line in front of the player, instead of all points that are in front of the player. Add a gap between each check like every 5px.

Answer (score 0):

I've been working on a similar project.
In the end I've used the `pygame.Rect.clipline()` and `pygame.Vector2.distance_to()` methods of pygame:

```
def intersect_rect(self,other) -> tuple[float,float]:
        cl=other.clipline(self.a.x,self.a.y,self.b.x,self.b.y)
        if cl:
            return cl[0] if self.a.distance_to(cl[0]) <self.a.distance_to(cl[1]) else cl[1]
        else:
            return
```

`self` and `other` are both of a class, that inherited form the `pygame.Rect` class. `self.a` and `self.b` are two `pygame.Vector2` objects. Where `self.a` is in the origin of the player and `self.b` the LoS.
This resulted in a speedup of 100x, compared to a pure python function.